# jQuery glDatePicker multiple data

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using the [glDatePicker](https://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/) plugin for our calendar event. But when 2 diffrent data on the same event occurs it only shows the last added. Is there a way to loop al items on the selected date? Could not find any input on looping this elements, console.log only shows the last input on date.

We need all data objects on given date, this can be multiple information on given date.

```
    var all_dates = [];

    $.each(agenda_json,function(index,value){
        var date_split = value.calendar.split("-");
        var date_event = {
            year: date_split[0],
            month: date_split[1],
            day: date_split[2]
        };
        var new_event = {
            date: new Date(date_event.year, (date_event.month - 1), date_event.day),
            data: { 
                message: value.post_title,
                onderwerp: value.onderwerp,
                link: value.post_link
            },
            cssClass: value.weekday + ' event_day',
            repeatMonth: false
        };

        all_dates.push(new_event);

    });


    $('#container_calendar').glDatePicker({

        cssName: 'flatwhite',
        showAlways: true,
        specialDates: all_dates,
        onClick: function(target, cell, date, data) {


            target.val(date.getFullYear() + ' - ' +
                        date.getMonth() + ' - ' +
                        date.getDate());

            if(data != null) {

                $('#title_input').html(data.message);
                $('.link_input').attr('href',data.link);

                if(data.onderwerp == '' || data.onderwerp == " "){

                    $('#onderwerp_input').hide();

                }else{

                    $('#onderwerp_input').show();
                    $('#onderwerp_input').html('<span>Onderwerp:</span><span>'+data.onderwerp+'</span>');
                }
            }

        },
        newcallback: function(){
            $('body').find(".event_day").eq(0).trigger( "click" );
        }
    });
```